# php get value from radio

Tags: php, html, function, class

I want to get code from html radio.
I want to check in function `dalje2()` what is choosen at form from `cetvrtiDio()` and echo right text. I tryed with `==` and `===` for compare, I tryed with `get` and `post`, even with and without space at `elseif` - `else if` but nothing work... Something display `idete desno`, while something display `Molimo vas da izaberete nešto od ponuđenog!` and some cases don't work at all... What is wrong here?

Thanks

```
<?php
class igra {
function cetvrtiDio() {
global $lang;
$desno = $lang['desno'];
$lijevo = $lang['lijevo'];
$ravno = $lang['ravno'];
$dalje = $lang['dalje'];
echo $lang['prvi-napad'].'<form>
    <input type="radio" name="izbor2" value="desno2">'.$desno.'<br />
    <input type="radio" name="izbor2" value="lijevo2">'.$lijevo.' <br />
    <input type="radio" name="izbor2" value="ravno2">'.$ravno.' <br />
    <input type="submit" name="dalje2" value="'.$dalje.'" />
    </form> ';
}
function dalje2() {
if(isset($_GET['izbor2'])==desno2) { echo 'idete desno'; }
elseif(isset($_GET['izbor2'])==lijevo2) { echo 'idete lijevo'; }
elseif(isset($_GET['izbor2'])==ravno2) { echo 'idete ravno'; }
else { echo 'Molimo vas da izaberete nešto od ponuđenog!';}
}
$igra = new igra;
if(isset($_GET['dalje2'])) {
$igra->dalje2();
}
```

Comment: The form looks to be submitted to GET, which all of your code uses, except for the check to see if you should run the function where you decide to use POST?

Comment: It is `$_GET` in original code... This may be mistake while testing. Anyway. Don't work with GET too... I edited that, but still don't work

Comment: Try `var_dump()`-ing `$_GET` before check for dalje2 and see what's in there.

Comment: function dalje2 ($_GET['izbor2'])==desno2) is supposed to be ($_GET['izbor2'])==$desno2) or ($_GET['izbor2'])=='desno2')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your if / else if statements is that you are using isset() to see if the variable exists and then trying taking the result of that compared to the strings you are looking for (i.e. "desno2"). It doesn't work that way and you don't need isset() in this logic. You use isset() properly in checking if the form has been submitted.

```
if($_GET['izbor2']=="desno2") { echo 'idete desno'; }
elseif($_GET['izbor2']=="lijevo2") { echo 'idete lijevo'; }
elseif($_GET['izbor2']=="ravno2") { echo 'idete ravno'; }
else { echo 'Molimo vas da izaberete nešto od ponuđenog!';}
```

**NOTE:** This works just fine. However, as noted in the comments you are mixing between $_POST and $_GET. You need to pick one, which probably is POST in your case and use for all.

Answer (score 2):

You are using php function isset and trying compare with string variable - it's not correct.
Try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['izbor2'])&&($_GET['izbor2']==$lang['desno'])) {
..
} elseif (...) {...}
```

And of course you can use switch function: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I searched, but I'm sure it will help me once I need it ;)